# Signing of Flex app fails with Ant script via Jenkins

Tags: flash, jenkins, apache-flex, ant, adt

I have AIR (Flex) Android app and Ant script to compile it and pack to APK. When I'm using this script on my local machine. it works fine.
But when trying to execute this script via Jenkins (I have localhost instance on my Windows), app compiles but can't be packed because of error:

```
could not load keystore file (password may be incorrect)
```

Here Ant target that fails:

```
<target name="pack">
    <exec executable="${FLEX_HOME}/bin/adt.bat" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="-package"/>
        <arg line="-target apk-captive-runtime"/>
        <arg line="-storetype pkcs12"/>
        <arg line="-keystore ${basedir}/build/cert/key.p12"/>
        <arg line="-storepass <password>"/>
        <arg line="${DEPLOY.dir}/appname.apk"/>
        <arg line="${DEPLOY.dir}/appdescriptor.xml"/>
        <arg line="-C ${DEPLOY.dir} appname.swf assets lang html markets.xml google-services.json"/>
        <arg line="-extdir ${basedir}/libs/anes/bin/release"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

And this is simple Jenkinsfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
node {
    stage('Build') {
        checkout scm
        bat 'ant'
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me and tell why I have an error when I'm launching script via Jenkins and how it can be solved?

Comment: Try using `arg`'s `value` attribute instead, with a separate arg for each string separated by whitespace.

Comment: That helped me. Great thanks!